# django 1.8 request.session['mysessionid'] = '12345678' don't save in the django_session table

Tags: django, python-2.7, session

I use django session to keep the user online like this(database is mysql):

```
request.session['mysessionid'] = '12345678'
```

but when i select in the django_session table ,i can't find the key

can anybody tell me what's the problem?

i use django 1.8

Comment: When do you do the select? The session won't be saved to the database until the end of the request.

Comment: i select after i finish the request

Comment: What are you running to do the 'select in the django_session table'? The session data is encoded, so you will not see your values if you do a select in SQL. Note also that setting `request.session['mysessionid']` does not set the session id, it just adds a key called `mysessionid` to the existing session.

Comment: @ Alasdair  what do you mean ,i can't see the encode "key",but i run "select * from django_session;" ,but there is no record create in past an hour

Comment: Django should [save the session at the end of the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) when you modify the session in a view. You haven't show enough code to explain why that might not be working. I think it would help if you expanded your question with more code, and explained what you are trying to do. Django has a very good authentication app that allows you to log users in and out, so I'm not sure why you're trying to use the session api directly to set session ids.

Comment: I can't use the django authentication app, but i want to use the session app,so i just add "request.session['mysessionid'] = '12345678'" in the view  function and i found it didn't save it into the database,so i want to know why

Comment: How do you know there are no sessions created in the last hour? The session table only stores the session key, data, and expiry date. I can't reproduce the problem. When I set `request.session['mysessionid']`, the session is saved to the db. Maybe somebody else will be able to suggest what is going wrong, but I don't think you've given enough information.